# USSD processing ,which os offers the most flexibility?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8, mobile-application, ussd

I need to implement the whole ussd processing functions,like dialer a ussd code programmatically,creating sessions and show  users input based on response,and after all things done,destroying sessions and all.

in my initial study,i found its not possible in android & in ios.

so my question is,what platform allows developer to do this?
can windows phone 8 be any help?
or any other mobile os except windows mobile ?

Answer (score 0):

It won't be possible to do on WP. You can't get access to system's dialer via code. Any input needs to be entered/confirmed by the user.

Comment: ok,so any other platform can be any help?

or can we do this by rooting the android phone?